# Change session time with service

Tags: session, tomcat

I would like to create a service/servlet that gets a time in minutes and change the session timeout value, meaning I want to change

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I know that

```
request.getSession(true).setMaxInactiveInterval(seconds);
```

changes only the current seesion and not all sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without somehow extending and depending upon Tomcat's own classes, I wouldn't know how you could change the default `<session-timeout>` programmatically once this has been set.

An alternative method might be to store a mutable session timeout value separately (perhaps in the database) - which your service could be responsible for updating/retrieving. You could then use a `HttpSessionListener` to modify the timeout for newly created sessions based on this value.

For example:

```
public class SessionTimeoutModifier implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        int timeout = sessionService.getSessionTimeout(); // Gets your value
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout); // Override default
    }

    ...
```

A web front end (servlet) could then be developed which could mutate your session timeout via `sessionService.setSessionTimeout(value)`.

Not the exact answer you're looking for but one possible way of achieving it.