# How can I get all open sessions?

Tags: session, spring-security

Im using spring security and I would like to loop over all the open session and change the timeout using `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout);`

I thought about using `SessionRegistry.getAllSessions()` but it only returns `SessionInformation` instances rather than `HttpSession` objects.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything in Spring Security that will do this - as you observed, the `SessionRegistry` doesn't retain `HttpSession` instances.

So you'll have to maintain your own map of active sessions, using an `HttpSessionListener` to record session creation and destruction (pretty much as described in the answer to [your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20377240/241990).

It would probably be a `Map<String,HttpSession>` where the key is the session ID.

You can then iterate over that map any time you want and modify the session objects. Don't forget to use a thread-safe map and remove any sessions when they expire (in the `sessionDestroyed` method).

Comment: The answer from @Luke Taylor should be marked as the answer. That's the way to do it and it works.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-track-logged-in-users also gives a nice overview about how this could be implemented